# How to configure SMTP on postfix ubuntu

Tags: postfix

I have no knowledge about postfix.

I have installed heirloom-malix and postfix.

I am using my ISP as mail sender.
i only want to send mails not receive.

So how in the postfix configure options how can i enter the SMTP of my ISP.
I could not find it in configuration menu

SMTP : mail.myisp.com

Answer (score 2):

in /etc/postfix/main.cf add

```
relayhost = mail.myisp.com
```

more info [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost).

and restart postfix

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

and watch logs while sending something

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Comment: log says MAIL FROM sender does not exist but i can't see MAIL FROM in main.cf file

Comment: @Mirage paste exact log here; what command do you use to send mail?